# Close modal when successful input

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I can display the validation errors in my modal but I don't know how to prevent the modal from closing when there is an error in my ajax function. Vice versa, I don't know how to close the modal when the input is successful. Help me with this.

Comment: It would be really awesome if you could post a piece of code, or, even better, a jsfiddle. Or you can hope a mind reader tries to help you...

Comment: I already took it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close your by the call a [modal('hide')](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) function from [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)